# use of for failing inside return statement inside React render method

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, jsx

The following code is failing with error of `Unexpected token` pointing at `for`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default React.createClass({
  render() {
    let nodes = JSON.parse(this.props.nodes)
    console.log(Object.keys(nodes));

    return (
      <ol>
        {
          for (var k in nodes){
              let val = nodes[k];
              let children = val.children;
              let content = val.content;
              <li key={k} id={k} content={content} />
              // <TChildPane key={k} count={children.length} />
          }
        }
      </ol>
    );
  }
});
```

`this.props.nodes` is passed from the parent component and is an object/hash
which is a collection of objects which contain 'children' and 'content' keys.  'children' key's value is an array.  'content' key's value is a string or bool or int etc...

Please let me know if you see a JSX related error!??

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should also add the whole payload inside `nodes` here. It will help others to give you correct suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not as easy as it should be  to find documentation on what you can and can't do inside jsx, but using for like this is one of those things you can't do. If you want to execute more complex code in place, move it into a function and call the function there instead:

```
export default React.createClass({
  renderList(nodes) {
    const list = [];
    for (const k in nodes){
      let val = nodes[k];
      let children = val.children;
      let content = val.content;
      list.push(<li key={k} id={k} content={content} />);
    }

    return list;
  }
  render() {
    let nodes = JSON.parse(this.props.nodes)
    return (
      <ol>
        { this.renderList(nodes) }
      </ol>
    );
  } 
});
```

Comment: Thank you!  I did come across the 'loop inside React JSX' question after posting the question.  But your addition of just moving the logic out - as long as the invoked method returns DOM or React elements - is cleaner and I will use that.  Thanks, once again.  Accepting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do something like this

```
{nodes.map(function(object, i){
    return <li key={object} id={object} content={object.content} />;
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try Array.map() for looping in React

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default React.createClass({
  render() {
    let nodes = JSON.parse(this.props.nodes)
    return (
      <ol>
        {
          nodes && nodes.map((item,index)=>{
            return(
              <li key={index} id={index} content={item.content} />
            )
          })
        }
      </ol>
    );
  }
});
```